try to parse a comma separated list - optional empty or full of spaces
a (optional empty) list of "a b c, a b c,..." should be parsed into a std:vector
it more or less works
remaining problems: empty string fails to parse and comma at end parses without fail
abc_rule >> *( ',' >> abc_rule )

its not clear to me why the parser allows the single comma at end - doesn't that fail the rule? a comma and then needs to come something that fullfill the abc_rule? the parse seems to be not greedy enough or something like that
and adding an ommitted *qi::space | at front to allow empty strings does not work
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct Out
{
    std::string a, b, c;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( Out, a, b, c )

int main()
{
    using It = std::string_view::const_iterator;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> identifier_rule = qi::char_( "a-zA-Z_" ) >> *qi::char_( "a-zA-Z0-9_" );

    #if 1
    qi::rule<It, Out()> abc_rule                     //
        = qi::omit[*qi::space] >> identifier_rule    //
          >> qi::omit[+qi::space] >> identifier_rule //
          >> qi::omit[+qi::space] >> identifier_rule //
          >> qi::omit[*qi::space];
    #else
    qi::rule<It, Out()> abc_rule = qi::skip( qi::space )[identifier_rule >> identifier_rule >> identifier_rule];
    #endif

    qi::rule<It, std::vector<Out>()> abc_list_rule = abc_rule >> *( ',' >> abc_rule );

    for( std::string_view test : {
             "a0 b0 c0,a1 b1 c1",            // valid
             "a0 b0 c0,",                    // !!!should be invalid - due to comma at end
             "XXXX",                         // invalid
             "a0 b0 c0",                     // valid
             "a0",                           // invalid
             "   "                           // !!!should be valid -> empty list
             " , ",                          // invalid
         } )
    {
        std::cout << "Parsing: [" << test << "]\n";
        It f = test.begin(), l = test.end();
        if( std::vector<Out> v; qi::parse( f, l, abc_list_rule, v ) )
        {
            std::cout << "Parsed:\n";
            std::string left( f, l );
            if( !left.empty() )
                std::cout << "left : [" << std::string( f, l ) << "]\n ";
            for( auto& o : v )
            {
                std::cout << "\nA: " << quoted( o.a ) << "\n"
                          << "B: " << quoted( o.b ) << "\n"
                          << "C: " << quoted( o.c ) << "\n";
            }
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Failed to parse " << quoted( test ) << " left: [" << std::string( f, l ) << "]\n";
    }
}


you can answer your own question by writing an answer below. But adding the answer into the question renders the whole question pointless. You can now either edit the answer into a proper answer or delete the question

Better demo of problem in form of test: https://godbolt.org/z/bTbG68Gdz

@Marek-R - thx for the test - im also using catch2 - but i try to keep the demo smaller for stackoverflow posts

Catch2 is a fine unit test framework.  Lightweight, easy to use, easy to understand.  (I've since switched to doctest, which is also a fine unit test framework.  Since I've switched, I suspect Catch2 v3.7 has addressed the performance and functionality gap between doctest and Catch2 v2.x.)

I do not like how doctest does value-parameterized test cases. It is not scalable and bug prone (especially when more then one variable needs to be changed).

I've noticed your self-answer. Let me raise you another idiomatic Spirit version. This improves several spots by

grouping the rules in a grammar instance
using implicit skippers
using p % q instead of p >> *(q >> p)
putting the post-validation requirement that all input should be consumed for success into the rule itself (qi::eoi!)
generalizing the testcases so we can verify them automatically

Live On Coliru
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using It     = std::string_view::const_iterator;

struct Out {
    std::string a, b, c;
    auto        operator<=>(Out const&) const = default;
};
using Outs = std::vector<Out>;
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Out, a, b, c)

static auto verdict(bool ok) { return ok ? "success" : "failure"; };

struct Parser : qi::grammar<It, Outs()> {
    Parser() : Parser::base_type(list_) {
        id_   = qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_");
        abc_  = id_ >> id_ >> id_;
        list_ = qi::skip(qi::space)[-(abc_ % ',') >> qi::eoi];

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((id_)(abc_)(list_))
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<It, Outs()>                list_;
    qi::rule<It, Out(), qi::space_type> abc_;
    // lexemes
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> id_;
};

int main() {
    static Parser const p;

    struct {
        std::string_view text;
        bool             valid;
        Outs             expected;
    } cases[]{
        {"a0 b0 c0,a1 b1 c1", true, {{"a0", "b0", "c0"}, {"a1", "b1", "c1"}}},
        {"  a0 b0 c0 ,   a1   b1 c1   ", true, {{"a0", "b0", "c0"}, {"a1", "b1", "c1"}}},
        {"a0 b0 c0,", false, {}},
        {"XXXX", false, {}},
        {"a0 b0 c0", true, {{"a0", "b0", "c0"}}},
        {"a0", false, {}},
        {"", true, {}},
        {"   ", true, {}},
        {" , ", false, {}},
    };

    for (auto const& [test, valid, expected] : cases) {
        It f = test.begin(), l = test.end();

        Outs actual;
        bool ok = qi::parse(f, l, p, actual);

        assert(!ok || (f == l)); // no unparsed input on success
        if (ok == valid && (!valid || expected == actual))
            continue;

        std::cout << "======\nTest case: " << quoted(test) << " " << verdict(ok) << "\n";
        if (ok != valid) {
            std::cout << "ERROR: Expected " << verdict(valid) << " but got " << verdict(ok) << "\n";
        }
        if (valid && expected != actual) {
            std::cout << "ERROR: Content mismatch\n";
        }
        for (auto& o : actual)
            std::cout << boost::fusion::as_vector(o) << "\n";
    }
}

Prints empty output - all test cases pass. Comment the lines
    if (ok == valid && (!valid || expected == actual))
        continue;

To get full output: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cacc6551ef6a15cb
======
Test case: "a0 b0 c0,a1 b1 c1" success
(a0 b0 c0)
(a1 b1 c1)
======
Test case: "  a0 b0 c0 ,   a1   b1 c1   " success
(a0 b0 c0)
(a1 b1 c1)
======
Test case: "a0 b0 c0," failure
(a0 b0 c0)
======
Test case: "XXXX" failure
======
Test case: "a0 b0 c0" success
(a0 b0 c0)
======
Test case: "a0" failure
======
Test case: "" success
======
Test case: "   " success
======
Test case: " , " failure


Note that on error the result is not atomically rolled back. See qi::hold

thanks for cleaning up my solution even further

I fixed it myself after looking at the code the needed time :)
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct Out
{
    std::string a, b, c;
};
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( Out, a, b, c )

int main()
{
    using It = std::string_view::const_iterator;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> identifier_rule = qi::char_( "a-zA-Z_" ) >> *qi::char_( "a-zA-Z0-9_" );

    qi::rule<It, Out()> abc_rule = qi::skip( qi::space )[identifier_rule >> identifier_rule >> identifier_rule];
    qi::rule<It, std::vector<Out>()> abc_list_rule = qi::skip( qi::space )[-( abc_rule >> *( ',' >> abc_rule ) )];

    for( std::string_view test : {
             "a0 b0 c0,a1 b1 c1",            // valid
             "  a0 b0 c0 ,   a1   b1 c1   ", // valid
             "a0 b0 c0,",                    // invalid - due to comma at end
             "XXXX",                         // invalid
             "a0 b0 c0",                     // valid
             "a0",                           // invalid
             "",                             // valid
             "   "                           // valid
             " , ",                          // invalid
         } )
    {
        std::cout << "Parsing: [" << test << "]\n";
        It f = test.begin(), l = test.end();
        // ">> qi::omit[*qi::space]" at end to eat in-between rest spaces ...
        if( std::vector<Out> v; qi::parse( f, l, abc_list_rule >> qi::omit[*qi::space], v ) )
        {
            std::cout << "Parsed:\n";
            std::string left( f, l );
            if( !left.empty() )
            {
                std::cout << "INVALID: left : [" << std::string( f, l ) << "]\n ";
            }
            else
            {
                for( auto& o : v )
                {
                    std::cout << "\nA: " << quoted( o.a ) << "\n"
                              << "B: " << quoted( o.b ) << "\n"
                              << "C: " << quoted( o.c ) << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to parse " << quoted( test ) << " left: [" << std::string( f, l ) << "]\n";
        }
    }
}

Output:
Parsing: [a0 b0 c0,a1 b1 c1]
Parsed:

A: "a0"
B: "b0"
C: "c0"

A: "a1"
B: "b1"
C: "c1"
Parsing: [  a0 b0 c0 ,   a1   b1 c1   ]
Parsed:

A: "a0"
B: "b0"
C: "c0"

A: "a1"
B: "b1"
C: "c1"
Parsing: [a0 b0 c0,]
Parsed:
INVALID: left : [,]
 Parsing: [XXXX]
Parsed:
INVALID: left : [XXXX]
 Parsing: [a0 b0 c0]
Parsed:

A: "a0"
B: "b0"
C: "c0"
Parsing: [a0]
Parsed:
INVALID: left : [a0]
 Parsing: []
Parsed:
Parsing: [    , ]
Parsed:
INVALID: left : [, ]

